# How to make Javascript Promise.all fun functions concurrently

Tags: javascript, parallel-processing, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

From what I understand from [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) documentation, it is possible run two or more functions simultaneously and wait until all of them to be completed. So I tried this:

```
function execute(id, max) {
    console.log('starting ' + id);

    console.time(id);
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < max; i ++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    console.timeEnd(id);
    return sum;
}

console.log("Declaring p1");
var p1 = Promise.resolve(() => execute("p1", 10000));
console.log("Declaring p2");
var p2 = Promise.resolve(() => execute("p2", 100000));

console.log("Calling Promise.all");
console.time("all"); 
Promise.all([p1, p2]).then((values) => console.log("Then: " + values));
console.timeEnd("all");
```

However, what I got (running in Chrome) was this:

```
Declaring p1
Declaring p2
Calling Promise.all
all: 0.599ms
Then: () => execute("p1", 10000),() => execute("p2", 100000)
```

So apparently, not only the functions were not running as well as the `then` method got them, not the results.

Even if I replace the promises by the original functions calls I had the same result:

```
function execute(id, max) {
    console.log('starting ' + id);

    console.time(id);
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < max; i ++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    console.timeEnd(id);
    return sum;
}

console.log("Calling Promise.all");
console.time("all");
Promise.all([() => execute("p1", 10000), () => execute("p2", 100000)])
  .then((values) => console.log("Then: " + values));
console.timeEnd("all");
```

The output was:

```
Calling Promise.all
all: 0.274ms
Then: () => execute("p1", 10000),() => execute("p2", 100000)
```

So, I think that I misunderstood the `Promise.all` usage. How do I execute parallel processing using Promises?

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

Comment: It is possible to run two **asynchronous** functions concurrently and await their results. Your loops are not asynchronous.

Comment: Could you give me an example? Do you want to say to use the promises inside the function?

Comment: He's saying that Promises don't execute code asynchronously; they execute asynchronous code.  You might be looking for something in the [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Worker) family for true parallelism.

Answer (score 3):

Promise.all takes array of promises and resolves as soon as all are resolved or one of them rejects. But promises are not asynchronous by spec, actually, total opposite is true: [Promise executor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is executed **immediately**. So if all of your executors are synchronous, then your promise chain is synchronous.

Maybe that helps a little bit to understand how it works:

```js
function execute(id, max) {
    console.log('starting ' + id);

    console.time(id);
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < max; i ++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    console.timeEnd(id);
    return sum;
}

console.log("Declaring p1");
var p1 = Promise.resolve(execute(1, 10));

console.log("Declaring p2");
var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('setting timeout..');
  setTimeout(() => resolve(execute(2,10)), 2000);
})

console.log("Calling Promise.all");
console.time("all");
console.time('results');
Promise.all([p1,p2])
  .then((results) => { 
      console.log('all results', results); 
      console.timeEnd('results'); 
  })
  .catch(console.error.bind(console));

console.timeEnd("all"); // Promise.all returns immediately
```

And thats the output:

```
Declaring p1
starting 1
1: 0.016ms
Declaring p2
setting timeout..
Calling Promise.all
all: 0.097ms
starting 2
2: 0.002ms
all results [45, 45]
results: 2001.144ms
```

Usually, Promises are used when calling some asynchronous API. But if you really want to run your own javascript asyncronously, you need to use Web Workers or something, depending on your platform.

Edit: Some quick googling about Web Workers and Promises, there is good looking library [promise-worker](https://github.com/nolanlawson/promise-worker). By good looking I mean, 100 % coverage and automated browser tests. Probably worth of inspecting, or even installing, if you want to go that route.